# How to get the count of an Excel in unix or Linux in datastage

Tags: datastage

Is there any possibility i can get the count of an excel in unix or linux.

I tried creating server routine & i am able to get the output link count but i am unable to get return value into a file or variable.

Please suggest,

Comment: Sorry but what is the count of an excel - could you please elaborate a little more and give examples

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher .. I want to capture the count of records from an excel. As we do for text files " wc -l Test.txt " , in the same way is there any possibility i can take count of records from an excel file. ?

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher .. We have a requirement : if the excel count of records >0 then we need to send a mail . We can achieve if the file is CSV , text but we have it as Excel and we are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of information (besides the data itself) that can be extracted from an Excel file - check out the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.unstructureddatastage.usage.doc/topics/uds_extract_data.html)

I could imageine two options for your goal:

- check a certain cell which would be filled/exist if the file is not empty
- check the filesize of an empty file and if the filesize is bigger than that it is not empty

Answer (score 0):

The Best approach will be,

1. Use 'Unstructured Data' stage from File section in palette to read the xlsx(excel file).
2. Use Aggregator stage  to take count of row , consider any column which will always be there in case the data comes into the file.
3. Write this count into a file.
4. use this as per your logical requirement.
5. After point 2 you can use transformer stage to handle count logic, whichever you find suitable.